# problem with WITH RECURSIVE in Sqldelight

Tags: sqlite, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

**SQLDelight Version**
2.0.0-alpha05

Hi guys
When I use WITH RECURSIVE in the sq file in sqldelight, it gives me the following error.
please help me.

**SQL Code:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE `name_tree` AS (

SELECT `id`, `parent_id`

FROM `tbl_accounts`

WHERE `id` = ?

UNION ALL

SELECT `c`.`id`, `c`.`parent_id`

FROM `tbl_accounts` `c`

JOIN `name_tree` `p` ON `c`.`id` = `p`.parent_id

AND `c`.`id` <> `c`.`parent_id`)

SELECT count(*) AS level` FROM name_tree`;
```

**Error:**

```
Execution failed for task ':data:generateMainMyDatabaseInterface'.
> A failure occurred while executing app.cash.sqldelight.gradle.SqlDelightTask$GenerateInterfaces
   > Failed to compile SqlCompoundSelectStmtImpl(COMPOUND_SELECT_STMT): [] :
     WITH RECURSIVE `name_tree` AS (
     SELECT `id`, `parent_id`
     FROM `tbl_accounts`
     WHERE `id` = ?
     UNION ALL
     SELECT `c`.`id`, `c`.`parent_id`
     FROM `tbl_accounts` `c`
     JOIN `name_tree` `p` ON `c`.`id` = `p`.parent_id
     AND `c`.`id` <> `c`.`parent_id`)
     SELECT count(*) AS `level` FROM `name_tree`
```